# Forge Design Automation - API サンプルの実行で、appが作成できない

Tags: node.js

下記のURLを参考にして Design Automation を試したいが、添付画像のようにnew app が作成できない状態となります。
Client ID と Client Secret の取得時には、作成するアプリにDesign Automation APIとData Management API も指定してあります。

https://adndevblog.typepad.com/technology_perspective/2022/08/design-automation-api-sample.html

添付画像は 1 Step 前で、Create/Updateを実行した後に表示された画像です。
どなたかお願いします。

[image]